# How to write UIView to a projector?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

How do I write a UIView to a projector that can work off the iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`UIScreen`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/Reference/UIScreen.html) class to present content on an external display (including a projector). You'll need to create a new UIWindow. [Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ExternalDisplay/Listings/Classes_ExternalDisplayViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010724-Classes_ExternalDisplayViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_6) is some relevant sample code from Apple as well.